# Syntax eroor grant roles

Tags: database, postgresql, roles

I have a problem when I try to grant role. My command is:

```
grant john.doe to john;
```

And I get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
```

I am using postgres database.

Comment: if your role is indeed `john.doe` use `grant "john.doe" to john;`

Comment: Thank you, I thought it can be solution so I tried `'john.doe'` but it did not work. However, it works with double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your role is indeed john.doe use

```
grant "john.doe" to john;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also
>   letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore
>   (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be
>   letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($). Note that
>   dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of
>   the SQL standard, so their use might render applications less
>   portable.

and further:

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or
>   quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of
>   characters in double-quotes (")

and lastly:

> Quoted identifiers can contain any character, except the character
>   with code zero. (To include a double quote, write two double quotes.)
>   This allows constructing table or column names that would otherwise
>   not be possible, such as ones containing spaces or ampersands. The
>   length limitation still applies.

Also most Postgres guys advise avoiding "camelCase" or "Other.Nam3s" as identifiers...

Comment: Thank you for the very complex explanation.

Comment: sure - my pleasure